# Mysql database approach on students, classes, grade promotion

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a confused about how to go about my Mysql database for the following case, although I studied some other solutions on the subject.

In a school, the children are grouped in classes. For example, the smallest class is 5-th grade, the second is 6-th, and so on , the last class is the 8-th.  Each class has about 20 students, and because the number of students is about 100  for every grade, several classes are formed and identifiers are used to uniquely identify a class ( eg: 5-th grade classes: 5A, 5B, 5C, 5D, 5E) .  Each year, classes promote to the next incremental grade. So 5-th class becomes 6-th, and so on.

Please help me with a database design idea/hint.

Answer (score 0):

Create one table for students (Students), one table for classes (Classes) and link them on say ... classId. The grade will not be a primary key in that table so when year passes you'll be able to update it withour changing the classId.

```
mysql> create table Classes (classId int, grade varchar(5), primary key(classId));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table Students (studentId int, name varchar(30), classId int, primary key(studentId), foreign key (classId) references Classes(classId));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like explicit data everywhere if it's possible. For example I would create separate grade (5,6,7,8 etc.) and grade id (A,B,C etc.) fields. This has a lot of the benefits. For example:

- Querying all the 5th grade classes won't result in range query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE grade LIKE "5%";` would.
- Same thing: you can easily query all the "B" classes without full scan (assuming you have the right indexes)

Other thing is that classes increment in every year. 5B becomes 6B then 7B. So this makes very hard to find the class you're looking for. I would create a start in field. Find the class "B" started in 2006 is easy and explicit (again the explicit stuff:) )

My recommendation would be:

```
CREATE TABLE school_class (
id smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
start_in smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
grade tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
grade_id CHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE student (
id mediumint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
class_id smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (class_id) references school_class(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Imo, for a school (1000 students?) the optimisations are probably not worth it, unless maybe some of OP's reporting requirements are very complex. A good idea for a database managing all schools at a national level though, with millions of students `;-)`